# What is the difference between 'gsutil compose' and 'gsutil cp' as a parallel composite upload

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

- What is the difference between `gsutil compose` and `gsutil -o
  GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=150M cp bigfile
  gs://your-bucket`?
- Does `gsutil compose` work only if we have many smaller source files?
- How will we  get these smaller files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Compose Operation

> The compose command creates a new object whose content is the
>   concatenation of a given sequence of source objects under the same
>   bucket.

```
gsutil compose gs://your-bucket/file1.txt  gs://your-bucket/file2.txt gs://your-bucket/file3.txt
```

The command above will concatenate the content of `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` into `file3.txt`. Large files can be concatenated as well, although it can only be done with up to 32 files in a single `gsutil compose` command. You need to specify and have these files beforehand. More on this [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose).

#### Parallel Composite Uploads

> If enabled (see below), a large file will be split into component
>   pieces that are uploaded in parallel and then composed in the cloud
>   (and the temporary components finally deleted). The maximum size of
>   each component piece is determined by the variable
>   `parallel_composite_upload_component_size`.

```
gsutil -o GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=150M cp bigfile gs://your-bucket
```

The command above will split `bigfile` into up to 32 pieces, and once they are uploaded, they will be composed into a single piece and the temporary files deleted, similarly to a compose operation. More on this [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#parallel-composite-uploads).

In short, the first command is used to compose an object; and the latter to split it, upload the pieces and then compose it in Cloud Storage.

Comment: what is the use case of Compose Operation?? I understand Parallel upload is used when there is a requirement to upload large files to storage bucket

Comment: @dhanabalanRangasamy To simply combine multiple files into one. Let's say you have a bunch of `.csv` files with related data in them, and want them to be in one single file for easier access - that's when `gsutil compose` would come in handy for example.